# Bind Label with result of count query

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net

I'm doing a `query` from my `Access` data base that give at result a `count`, if I'm not wrong a count array give an `array`, so first I need to convert the `array` to `int` and the show into the `label`

This is my `query` it is on a folder named `connections` and inside is the `class` whit name `genera-conections` where I make all the `querys` that I need

```
/***********GET ALL THE FAKE TOOLS FROM FCH*************/
public class area_success_FCH
{
    public DataTable Sfchconnect()
    {
        string myConnectionString = @"C:\\Users\\gutiece\\Desktop\\database\\" + "Database1.accdb";

        DataTable SfchTable = new DataTable();

        OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection();
        OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
        OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter();
        DataSet dataset = new DataSet();

        try
        {
            connection.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data source= " + myConnectionString;
            bool ok = System.IO.File.Exists(myConnectionString);
            String qry = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM area WHERE standby = 1 AND area = 'FCH'";
            command.Connection = connection;
            command.CommandText = qry;

            adapter.SelectCommand = command;

            command.Connection.Open();
            OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader(); // close conn after 
            SfchTable.Load(reader);
            if (!reader.IsClosed)
            {
                reader.Close();
            }

            return SfchTable;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
        }
        return SfchTable;
    }
}
/*******************************************************/
```

and in the Code behind of my `dashboard.aspx` a "common" page I call like this:

```
/********************************FILL COUNT CLOUD******************************/
    connections.area_success_FCH Sfchconnect = new connections.area_success_FCH();
    connections.area_success_FCH SfchTable = new connections.area_success_FCH();
    /******************************************************************************/
```

I want to fill a `Label` on `dashboard.aspx` with the `count` result but I don't know how to make it

hope someone can help me

Comment: FYI, with the `@` symbol in front of a string, you don't need to double-up the `\ ` character (in your `myConnectionString` assignment).

Comment: @RufusL Thanks for the advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `SqlCommand.ExecuteScalar()` and cast it to an int:

```
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM area WHERE standby = 1 AND area = 'FCH'";
Int32 count = (Int32) cmd.ExecuteScalar();
```

Then set the label:

```
label.Text = count.ToString();
```

Setting label from another class:

```
class withCode{
   cmd.CommandText = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM area WHERE standby = 1 AND area = 'FCH'";
    public static Int32 count = (Int32)cmd.ExecuteScalar();        
}

class withLabel{
     label.Text = withCode.count.ToString();
}
```

Comment: but that code is when I have the query in the same side of the code, in mace isn't lake that :/

Comment: Updated the code above. Let me know if it works and resolves your issue.

Comment: actually it works, I only modify some code with your example. Thanks